# the meaning of the sentence in bold is unclear to me

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The old woman held out her hand to each of us in turn. Thereafter, she never touched me if she could avoid it. If I offered my hand, she would brush my fingers aside as if waving away a fly. She didn't enter our service that evening — that would have been unworthy, improper. She enlisted in it. As she was leaving, she said to my husband: "I wish the master good night." He stared after her. **There was no man on the planet to whom this magnificent word might less apply**. But that was how she addressed him until her dying day. It took a while for him to get used to his new title, and answer to it.

Does it mean:  this magnificent word is appropriate for every man?

Source: The door: The novel by Magda szabo

Comment: The narrator says that the title 'Master' was not appropriate for her husband. With some exaggeration, she claims that she cannot imagine any man for whom it would be less appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, so does she mean:  there was no man in the planet that this title would be approprite. I get somehow confused.

Comment: She means "the master" is not an apprpriate name for her husband, like Kate says.

Comment: In other words, the title is _more inappropriate_ for her husband than it would be for any other man in the world.

Comment: I have just done so in my last comment! _There is no other man whom it would be less suitable to address as 'Master' than it is to address her husband that way._ Is that any clearer?

Comment: Thanks, sorry My problem was I didnot notice at the word "less" before "apply"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means

> There is no one on Earth less worthy of the title of "Master" than my husband.